# Solving two modular equations using the chinese remainder theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, chinese-remainder-theorem

We've got the following system
$$
\begin{split}
10^{33}X &\equiv 47 \pmod{51} \\
 4^{62}  &\equiv  8 \pmod{9}
\end{split}
$$

And I've managed to rewrite this as
$$
\begin{split}
X &\equiv 2 \pmod{3} \\
X &\equiv 3 \pmod{17} \\
X &\equiv 35 \pmod{9}
\end{split}
$$

However I'm not sure how to follow on this. Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Aren't you missing an $X$ in the second congruence? Also for CRT, the moduli are supposed to be relatively prime.

Comment: Note that $35\equiv 8\pmod 9$ so you can drop the $X\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ since it is covered by $X\equiv 8 \pmod 9$.

Comment: You can solve the pair of congruences, $X\equiv 3 \pmod {17}$, $X\equiv 8\pmod 9$ by a very rapid trial and error.  Just use the first to write $X\in \{3,20,37, \cdots\}$ and just check until you note that $X=71$ works.  Of course you can do it systematically, but with such small numbers I think this way is fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that $X\equiv8\pmod{9}$ and this condition implies the first one $X\equiv2\pmod{3}$.

Hint: Try to find two numbers $X_1,X_2$ such that $$\begin{matrix}X_1&\equiv 1\pmod{9}\\X_1&\equiv 0\pmod{17}\end{matrix}\qquad\begin{matrix}X_2&\equiv  0\pmod{9}\\X_2&\equiv 1\pmod{17}\end{matrix}$$ Then $X=8X_1+3X_2\pmod{9\times17}$.